# Extract image from pdf in specific position

Tags: c#, itext

I have inserted the image in the pdf using itextsharp as shown below and I tried all the possible solutions to extract it with using the coordinates.

```
String pathin = pdf.src;
String pathout = "C:\\....";
string signedFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathin);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFileName);
image1.RotationDegrees = 270f;
image1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
image1.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
image1.ScalePercent(50f, 50f);

cb.AddImage(image1);
stamper.Close();
fs.Close();
Console.Read();
pdf.src = pathout;
```

Is there any way to use itextsharp to extract image from position (0,0)?

Comment: *"I tried all the possible solutions to extract it with using the coordinates."* - As extraction is possible, one of all those *possible solutions* must have worked, and you must have made an error in your implementation of that solution. ... In other words: What have you tried, how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pseudo-code:

- implement `IEventListener`
- parse the page you are interested in, `CanvasProcessor` takes an `IEventListener` implementation in its constructor, every time it finishes rendering text, an image, or a path, it will notify the `IEventListener`
- `IEventListener` has a method called `eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)`. One of the types will be responsible for images
- cast `IEventData` to `ImageRenderInfo`
- derive the coordinates from the `ImageRenderInfo` object
- if the coordinates happen to contain `Point(0, 0)` then (temporarily) store the image in a variable of your `IEventListener`

code sample (java, iText7)
**disclaimer**: the following code does not handle rotation

```
class MyImageSeek implements IEventListener{

private int pageNr = 0;
private Map<Integer, Map<Rectangle, BufferedImage>> images = new HashMap<>();

public MyImageSeek(PdfDocument pdfDocument){
    PdfCanvasProcessor canvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(this);
    for(int i=1;i<=pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();i++) {
        images.put(i, new HashMap<Rectangle, BufferedImage>());
        pageNr = i;
        canvasProcessor.processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(i));
    }
}

@Override
public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
    if(type != EventType.RENDER_IMAGE)
        return;
    ImageRenderInfo imageRenderInfo = (ImageRenderInfo) data;

    int x = (int) imageRenderInfo.getStartPoint().get(0);
    int y = (int) imageRenderInfo.getStartPoint().get(1);
    int w = (int) imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I11);
    int h = (int) imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I22);

    try {
        images.get(pageNr).put(new Rectangle(x,y,w,h), imageRenderInfo.getImage().getBufferedImage());
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

@Override
public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
    return null;
}

public Map<Rectangle, BufferedImage> getImages(int pageNr){
    return images.get(pageNr);
}
}
```

and this is the main method to call this class

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\lookAtMe.pdf")));
MyImageSeek meeseek = new MyImageSeek(pdfDocument);
for(Map.Entry<Rectangle, BufferedImage> en : meeseek.getImages(1).entrySet())
    System.out.println(en.getKey() + "\t" + en.getValue());
```

Comment: is it possible to have a sample of how the code will be?

Comment: Using `imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I11)` and `imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I22)` as width and height respectively will only work properly if effectively no rotation (let alone skewing) is involved.